# Mocking a function in Jest not returns the expected value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, mocking

I got AWS lambda function which I want to unit test it using Jest.

As part of the code I got another file to make http calls, which currently I using as a mock.

During another unit test case I want to have another scenario to check by using a mock.

I tried several ways using Jest to do so, but nothing made my function to return the needed result from the mocked function:

**First try:**

```
const api_response_utils = require('api_response_utils').default;
const mock = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(["new return value"])
api_response_utils.get = mock;
```

**Second try:**

```
 jest.mock("api_response_utils", () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual("api_response_utils"),
      get: () => {
        return ["a", "b"]
      },
      sendResponse:() => {
        return ["a", "b"]
      },
    }));
```

Is there any other way to make it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this (I am assuming `api_response_utils` is a local file)

```
const api_response_utils = require('./api_response_utils')

jest.mock("./api_response_utils", () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual("./api_response_utils"),
      get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(["a", "b"]),
      sendResponse: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(["a", "b"]),
    }));
```